# Unknown System Variable - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-insert, database-trigger

The student table looks like this

```
Name varchar(255), sub1 int(11), sub2 int(11), sub3 int(11)
```

I created a trigger to update sub3 based on the sum of sub1 and sub2,

```
create Trigger subject_total
after INSERT
on
student
for each row
set sub3 = sub1 + sub2;
```

While executing the above code, the following error is encountered.
Error Code: 1193. Unknown system variable 'sub3'

DB: MYSQL

Comment: Unfortunately, this looks like a poor place to start. A database table is not a spreadsheet, and any time you find yourself with enumerated column names (or columns like 'Maths', 'French', 'English', which are all essentially holding the same kind of thing) alarm bells should start ringing. Consider revising your schema accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you want a `before insert` trigger that sets the value of `sub3`.

That would be:

```
create trigger subject_total
before insert on student
for each row
set new.sub3 = new.sub1 + new.sub2;
```

Within the trigger, you can access the values that are being inserted using pseudo-table `new`.

Answer (score 2):

If `sub3` must be ALWAYS equal to the sum of `sub1` and `sub2` I'd recommend to remove static field and replace it with calculated one:

```
ALTER TABLE subject_total
DROP COLUMN sub3,
ADD COLUMN sub3 INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (sub1 + sub2) STORED;
```

And you do not need in the trigger at all.

Comment: I am unsure why this answer was downvoted - in my opinion it does provide a solution to the question (although not using a trigger). FYI my answer was anonymously downvoted too.

Answer (score 0):

Revise your schema as follows:

```
student
student_id, student_details, etc

student_marks
student_id, subject_id, score
```

Now the problem is trivial, and note that is no benefit here in storing derived data, and hence no need for a trigger.